# Se puede cambiar directamente el input hdmi de un tv samsung IR?

Tags: nodejs, express, samsung

Tengo una aplicación hecha en electrón con Node.js, express y que sirve más como un servidor, que envía comandos por IR a distintos dispositivos, para hacer distintas acciones, la acción que quiero realizar es el cambio de entradas del televisor, pero no he encontrado un comando exacto

¿Quería saber, si hay algún método para cambiar de HDMI 1 a HDMI 2 usando el protocolo IR o, por otro lado, usar un método distinto, como lo sería por alguna API?

¿Existe algo por el estilo?

El televisor en cuestión es un samsung AU7000